# Display a matrix with putting a common factor in sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to display a matrix with putting an extracted common factor on outside of the matrix after matrix calculation in sympy.

I wrote below code.

```
from sympy import *
a = symbols("a")
b = symbols("b")

A = Matrix([exp(I*a),exp(I*a)*exp(I*b)])
print simplify(A)
```

I got below output.

```
Matrix([
[      exp(I*a)],
[exp(I*(a + b))]])
```

However, I want to get below output.

```
exp(I*a)*Matrix([
[      1],
[exp(I*b)]])
```

I tried collect(A,exp(I*a)) and got follow error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-65-834f4c326df4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Anaconda2/Programs/test/untitled44.py', wdir='C:/Anaconda2/Programs/test')

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Anaconda2/Programs/test/untitled44.py", line 14, in <module>
    collect(A,exp(I*a))

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\simplify\simplify.py", line 451, in collect
    if expr.is_Mul:

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\matrices.py", line 3084, in __getattr__
    "%s has no attribute %s." % (self.__class__.__name__, attr))

AttributeError: MutableDenseMatrix has no attribute is_Mul.
```

I know a way to extract a common factor for a element of a matrix like follow link.
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8442

But it's not my desire.

How should I do?

Comment: Whenever you say that you've encountered an error, please be sure to include the whole error message in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry for my incompleteness. I add tried collect command and got error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not think `Sympy` provides a function for the task you want. However, you can do this manually, as per the method proposed in the accepted answer of a similar question asked in the Mathematica SE ([link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44500/factor-a-vector)).

The idea is to extract the common factor of the polynomial elements via `gcd` and then use `MatMul` with the `evaluate=False` option in order to restrict `Sympy` from performing the scalar-matrix multiplication.

```
import sympy as sp

a, b = sp.symbols('a, b')

A = sp.Matrix([sp.exp(sp.I * a), sp.exp(sp.I * a) * sp.exp(sp.I * b)])
g = sp.gcd(tuple(A))

A_v2 = sp.MatMul(g,(A/g),evaluate = False)
print(A_v2)
```

> ```
> exp(I*a)*Matrix([
> [       1],
> [exp(I*b)]])
> ```

Comment: Thank you very mach for your help. It's a nice way!

Comment: You should use `MatMul` for products with matrices.

Comment: @asmeurer Thank you for the correction. Edited the answer.